# Heroku and mLab: The page you were looking for doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I am trying to deploy my Rails 5 app to Heroku. I just set up mLab, but there must be something wrong as my Heroku app page says "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

I followed the instructions [seen here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab). I'm a beginner though so I didn't fully understand everything I was doing, to be perfectly honest.

Here's my gemfile, in case it's needed:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.0.1'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'mongoid', '6.1.0'
  gem 'bson_ext'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

The relevant part from mongoid.yml:

```
# mongoid
#
production:
  clients:
    default:
     # The standard MongoDB connection URI allows for easy
     # replica set connection setup.
     # Use environment variables or a config file to keep your
     # credentials safe e.g. <%= ENV['MONGODB_URI'] %>.
     uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>

     options:
       # The default timeout is 5, which is the time in seconds
       # for a connection to time out.
       # We recommend 15 because it allows for plenty of time
       # in most operating environments.
       connect_timeout: 15
```

And finally my Heroku logs:

```
2017-03-14T10:29:02.337819+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.2.6-p396), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
2017-03-14T10:29:02.337838+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2017-03-14T10:29:02.337956+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:13166
2017-03-14T10:29:02.338149+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-03-14T10:29:54.966609+00:00 app[api]: Detach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-lively-51943) by user ellis.jas48@gmail.com
2017-03-14T10:29:54.966609+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user ellis.jas48@gmail.com
2017-03-14T10:29:55.462644+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user ellis.jas48@gmail.com
2017-03-14T10:29:55.561366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-03-14T10:29:55.561865+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-03-14T10:29:56.262337+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-03-14T10:29:56.276153+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2017-03-14T10:29:56.276275+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2017-03-14 10:29:56 +0000 ===
2017-03-14T10:29:56.276277+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2017-03-14T10:29:56.276361+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-03-14T10:29:56.401600+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-03-14T10:29:59.161344+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 17091 -e production`
2017-03-14T10:30:03.899834+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:17091
2017-03-14T10:30:03.899797+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-03-14T10:30:03.899835+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-03-14T10:30:05.128451+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2017-03-14T10:30:05.128523+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.2.6-p396), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
2017-03-14T10:30:05.128562+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-03-14T10:30:05.128624+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2017-03-14T10:30:05.128812+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:17091
2017-03-14T10:30:05.129253+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-03-14T10:30:05.712457+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-03-14T11:01:53.466180+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-03-14T11:01:53.466824+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-03-14T11:01:54.158015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-03-14T11:01:54.172597+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2017-03-14T11:01:54.172605+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2017-03-14 11:01:54 +0000 ===
2017-03-14T11:01:54.172607+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2017-03-14T11:01:54.172608+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-03-14T11:01:54.352041+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-03-14T11:06:04.603021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2017-03-14T11:06:04.603286+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-03-14T11:06:07.426080+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 43385 -e production`
2017-03-14T11:06:11.300942+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-03-14T11:06:11.300974+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:43385
2017-03-14T11:06:11.300975+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-03-14T11:06:12.172201+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2017-03-14T11:06:12.172221+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.2.6-p396), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
2017-03-14T11:06:12.172252+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-03-14T11:06:12.172297+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2017-03-14T11:06:12.172395+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:43385
2017-03-14T11:06:12.172620+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-03-14T11:06:12.284924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-03-14T11:06:12.661213+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=aqueous-dawn-54394.herokuapp.com request_id=a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e fwd="115.70.240.190" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=1744 protocol=https
2017-03-14T11:06:12.667112+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-14T11:06:12.667025 #4]  INFO -- : [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] Started GET "/" for 115.70.240.190 at 2017-03-14 11:06:12 +0000
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669277+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-14T11:06:12.669224 #4] FATAL -- : [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant PeopleController):
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669228+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-14T11:06:12.669159 #4] FATAL -- : [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e]   
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669326+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-14T11:06:12.669278 #4] FATAL -- : [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e]   
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669418+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-14T11:06:12.669350 #4] FATAL -- : [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `const_get'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669420+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `block in constantize'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669421+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669422+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669422+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669423+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in `get'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669424+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:614:in `constantize'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669424+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:81:in `controller_class'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669425+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in `controller'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669426+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `serve'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669427+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669428+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669428+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669429+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669431+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669432+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669432+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669433+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669434+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669435+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669435+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669437+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669436+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669437+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669438+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669439+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669439+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669440+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669444+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669445+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669446+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669447+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669447+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669448+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669449+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669450+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669450+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669452+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669453+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669453+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669454+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669455+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669454+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669456+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669457+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669457+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669458+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `call'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.669459+00:00 app[web.1]: [a02ddf92-7774-40c4-854b-8fc4fe466f0e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-03-14T11:06:12.981986+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aqueous-dawn-54394.herokuapp.com request_id=206b3bd5-6187-4397-b56e-6f89628f323f fwd="115.70.240.190" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
```

I know that's a lot to read, so big thank you to anyone who replies!

EDIT: Here is routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :people, except: [:show]

  root to: "people#index"
end
```

people_controller.rb:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  def new
    @person = Person.new
  end

  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)

    if @person.save
      redirect_to people_path, notice: "The person has been created!" and return
    end
    render 'new'
  end

  def edit
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])

    if @person.update_attributes(person_params)
      redirect_to people_path, notice: "#{@person.first_name} #{@person.last_name} has been updated!" and return
    end

    render 'edit'
  end

  def destroy
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    @person.destroy

    redirect_to people_path, notice: "#{@person.first_name} #{@person.last_name} has been deleted!" and return
  end
private
  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :notes)
  end
end
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your database. Rather its a routing error `ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant PeopleController)`

Comment: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant PeopleController):

Comment: could you include the routes.rb file and the peoplecontroller thanks

Comment: Ok I added it in. I am really not sure what is causing the routing error. :(